# http post sends wrong data

Tags: python, http, python-requests

i have create a simple input form/fields with tkinter 
what i wanted was to send the entered information to a webserver 
this is the code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import requests
API_ENDPOINT = "http://123.123.123.12"

def send_req():
    r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data) 
    # extracting response text 
    pastebin_url = r.text 
    print("The pastebin URL is:%s"%pastebin_url)

    e1.delete(0, tk.END)
    e2.delete(0, tk.END)
    e3.delete(0, tk.END)
    e4.delete(0, tk.END)
master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master, text="first name").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master, text="last name").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(master, text="Add").grid(row=2)
tk.Label(master, text="Phone").grid(row=3)

e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)
e3 = tk.Entry(master)
e4 = tk.Entry(master)

e1.insert(10, "")
e2.insert(10, "")
e3.insert(10, "")
e4.insert(10, "")

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
e4.grid(row=3, column=1)
data = {'key1': e1, 
                'key2':e2, 
                'key3':e3, 
                'key4':e4}

tk.Button(master, text='send',command=send_req).grid(row=4,column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=5,)

master.mainloop()

tk.mainloop()
```

and no matter what i enter into the fields at the client end, i always get this at server side instead of the fields data:

[image]

Comment: Inside `send_req`.. what is the value for `r.status_code`?

Comment: what is r.status_code?

Comment: It's the status code of the respose... inisde this function, just try to print `r.status_code`

Comment: yep the status code is 200

Comment: has the answer solved the issue? if yes please accept the answer or let us know the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly there is issue with the code. 
First, you should pass `data` as argument to `send_req`

Second, you are assigning `key1` to `e1` which is a `tkinter Entry` object not a text.

I believe you want to send text from Text field.
So you need to do this:

```
data = {'key1': e1.get(), 
                'key2':e2.get(), 
                'key3':e3.get(), 
                'key4':e4.get()}
```

Hope this helps.